# How do I change a specific image when a list class is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I have website which is made with materialize. I am using a `ul` with three `li` elements which are all collapsible. On top of that is a card with an image. I want to change the image when a `li` element is active, respectively, expanded.

There were some similar question on here already, but none really fit my problem.
Following is an example layout of my code.

```
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-image">
  <img src="img/image-1.jpg"/>
 </div>
 <ul class="collapsible expandable">
  <li class="active">
   <div class="collapsible-header">
   <div class="collabsible-body">
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The active class appears when you expand the respective `li` element. It disappears again if you close it.
`image-1.jpg` should change, corresponding to the `li` element when the respective `li` element is active.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you add the "active" to the li lement with javascript/jQuery? Why don't you give the image the "active" class, too?

Answer (score 1):

If you are the one toggling the class between `active` and `collapsed`, you could add additional code to your toggle function which can swap out the `src` of that image.

If not, you can use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to fire a callback when the class of that DOM element has changed. You'll still have to update the `src` in response to the class change.

```js
// will watch target element for changes to the 'class'
// attribute and fire the callback with an array of the
// class names when changed
const observeClassList = (element, callback) => {
  const config = { attributes: true }
  const mutationCallback = mutationsList => {
    mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
      if (mutation.attributeName === `class`)
        callback([...mutation.target.classList])
    })
  }
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback)
  observer.observe(element, config)
}

// example implementation
// it's up to you to watch for any class changes you desire on any element,
// and make changes to any other element (ie updating and image src) when desired
const changeImageOnToggle = (imageElement, toggleElement) => {
  const callback = classArray => {
    if (classArray.includes(`active-li`)) {
      // update the image element src
    }
  }
  observeClassList(toggleElement, callback)
}
```

Comment: In your first suggestion, do you mean the user toggling the class between `active` and `collapsed`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
$('.active-li').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  var new_src = $(this).attr('data-img');
  $(".card-image img").attr("src",new_src);
  $(".card-image p").text('src of this img is '+new_src);
});
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-image">
  <img src="img/image-1.jpg"/>
  <p > </p>
 </div>
 <ul class="collapsible expandable">

  <li data-img="img/image-2.jpg" class="active-li">
  Lorem
  </li>
  <li data-img="img/image-1.jpg" class="active-li">
  Lorem
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The image swapping worked perfectly, but now my `li` elements won't expand anymore. Any idea?

Comment: Your <li> elements won't expand anymore? Can you say more about this?

Comment: I put your jquery part in my `init.js` and modified the `li` elements like you did and put in my own images. Now when I click on a `li` element, the picture changes but the `li` element won't expand anymore like it did before. There is a header and a body with text inside every `li` element. I do have jquery loaded in my scripts.

Comment: This is example code. Click() function in this case may be block your click() function. If you also have a function click with these <li> tag, i think you need group them in a function.

Comment: $('.active-li').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  var new_src = $(this).attr('data-img');
  $(".card-image img").attr("src",new_src);
  $(".card-image p").text('src of this img is '+new_src);
/// add your expand code here
});

Answer (score 0):

I used Midos logic and it worked fine ... but how do I return the image back to its original image?

```
    $('.egg').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  var new_src = $(this).attr('data-img');
  $(".green-egg img").attr("src",new_src);
  return;
});
```